# How to include static library built from D sources in Makefile.am?

Tags: static-libraries, automake, d

I'm writing a utility library `libdog-dev` for programming with D language, here is the `Makefile.am`:

```
sited2dir = /usr/include/d2/site
lib32dir = ${libdir}/i386-linux-gnu
# lib64dir = ${libdir}/x86_64-linux-gnu

lib32_LIBRARIES = \
    i386/libdog.a

# lib64_LIBRARIES = \
#     x86_64/libdog.a

i386/libdog.a:
    mkdir -p i386
    dmd -lib -m32 -of$@ -op -Hdi386/include/ `find src/ -name '*.d'`

x86_64/libdog.a:
    mkdir -p x86_64
    dmd -lib -m64 -of$@ -op -Hdx86_64/include/ `find src/ -name '*.d'`

# Since the header files for i386/x86_64 are the same, let's just pick the i386 one.
install-data-hook: 
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(sited2dir)
    rsync -av i386-linux-gnu/include/ $(DESTDIR)$(sited2dir)
```

it's working, however, something I'm still unclear:

- I need to include `AC_PROG_CC` and `AC_PROG_RANLIB` in `configure.ac`, which should be unnecessary, because there is no c/c++ source in this project. Missing the two statements will result in error.
- I can only include single `libdog.a` in the `Makefile.am`. I had comment out the x86-64 one in the code above, if I included it, automake will show the error:

  ```
  cd . && /bin/bash /home/lenik/tasks/1-uni/devel/libdog-dev/missing --run automake-1.11 --gnu Makefile
  Makefile.am: object `libdog.$(OBJEXT)' created by `x86_64/libdog.c' and `i386/libdog.c'
  make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
  ```

  I want to include both versions for i386 and x86-64 in one package, just like the official `dmd` package for Debian:

  ```
  ...                              (install tree of the dmd-2.059-0 package)
  |-- lib/
  |   |-- i386-linux-gnu/
  |   |   `-- libphobos2.a
  |   `-- x86_64-linux-gnu/
  |       `-- libphobos2.a
  ```
- I had hard coded the arch name `i386-linux-gnu` and `x86_64-linux-gnu` in the Makefile source, however, it should be generated somehow..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Automake will try to find C/C++ sources for files listed in `_LIBRARIES` targets. So, just change them to `_DATA` targets:

   ```
   lib32_DATA = \
       i386/libdog.a

   lib64_DATA = \
       x86_64/libdog.a
   ```
2. You can generate the name `i386-linux-gnu` or `x86_64-linux-gnu` of the host system by running:

   ```
   dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE
   ```

   You can also get the library path from `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*`.